# method to validate that amount should be of type integer return type

Tags: java, string, integer, pojo

I am getting an amount in an object through the getter method of pojo
but that amount getter method return type is set as string in pojo
as shown below

```
//setting need to be done in pojo
private String amount;

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
```

let say below that there is object h and I am retrieving it like

```
h.getAmount()
```

now I need to develop a validator that will validate the that amount should
be of type integer and if it is not then it will throw the exception
Please advise how can I develop a seprate method that will check whether
the amount is in integer or not and on the basis of it
will return true or false , as like shown below

```
// Validate the amount is in integer
private boolean isValidAmount (String Amount) {
    boolean valid = false;
//code to check whether the Amount is integer or not, if integer then
//return true else return false
}
```

I have updated the post as it  throws number format exception , please advise

Answer (score 3):

You could just try to parse it, and return true iff the parse succeeds.

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(amount);
    return true;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
}
```

**Edit**

I just re-read the question and noticed that it seems the only thing you want to do with this true/false value is to possibly raise an exception if the string couldn't be parsed. In that case, you can get rid of that boolean middleman:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(amount);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new MyWhateverException(amount);
}
```

Comment: @user2200150 I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and use `Integer.parseInt(someString);`
This will throw a `NumberFormatException` if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = false;
try{
  int amount = Integer.parseInt(amount);
  flag = true;
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
flag = flase;
}

return flag;
```

if the amount is in integer format then it will not through any exception
otherwise it will through NumberFormatException.

Get nmore details of parseInt() [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isValidAmount (Object h){
   try {
       Integer.parseInt(h.amount);
       return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

try this out, may work for u